# need to convert silverlight to exe

Tags: silverlight, exe

Actually I need to do Intranet chat application(Desktop Application).

For that I just download the application from net. Its Squiggle. Its developed by silverlight.

I just download the source code from that site and i did some modifications. Now I need the exe file for that application. I don't know how to convert the application to exe file, then only I can install that application to another system.

Am basically php developer, so I don't know how to convert this so kindly guide me to finish this project. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are only doing it for Intranet use, why change it from a Silverlight app at all? What additional features require that?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try it. But this seems like what you need: 
http://weblogs.asp.net/alnurismail/archive/2010/05/24/a-distributable-exe-silverlight-oob-application.aspx

Here is another explanation (unfortunately in German :( ) http://www.heise.de/developer/artikel/Silverlight-Anwendungen-ausserhalb-des-Browsers-per-Batch-Setup-MSI-oder-Click-Once-verteilen-1077886.html

Hope this helps,

TJ